# Why is GridLayout positioned in left bottom of the screen?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to add buttons into ScrollView. Each button contains GridLayout (one row) with two Labels ("First" and "Second"). Buttons are added without a hitch but the GridLayout with labels is positioned in the left bottom corner of the screen instead of inside the buttons.

I am new to Kivy. Any help would be great.

If you notice some bad practices codewise please let me know.

Output:
[image]

Widget hierarchy:

```
Screen
-- GridLayout (Blue background) 
---- Label ("Delivery Orders") 
---- ScrollView (Green background) 
------ BoxLayout (Light Blue background) 
-------- GridLayout (Red background)
---------- Button
------------ GridLayout (Yellow background)
-------------- Label ("First")
-------------- Label ("Second")
```

kv file

```
<DeliveryOrdersScreen>:
    name: "delivery_orders_screen"
    id: delivery_orders_screen

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.9
        pos_hint: {"center_x" : 0.5, "center_y" : 0.5}
        spacing: 20
        size: self.parent.size
        pos: self.parent.pos

        Label:
            text: "Delivery Orders"
            font_size: 60
            bold: True

        ScrollView:
            size_hint: 1, None
            do_scroll_x: False
            do_scroll_y: True
            size: root.width, root.height - 200
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}

            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 1, 0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            BoxLayout:
                id: scroll_box
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.minimum_height
                spacing: 10

                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0, 1, 1, 1
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size

                TestLayout:
                    Button:
                        DoubleLayout:

                TestLayout:
                    Button:
                        DoubleLayout:

                TestLayout:
                    Button:
                        DoubleLayout:

<TestLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    id: test_layout
    size_hint: 1, None
    cols: 1
    spacing: 5

<DoubleLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 0, 0.5
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    id: double_layout
    size_hint: 1, None
    pos: self.pos
    size: self.size
    rows: 1

    Label:
        text: "first"

    Label:
        text: "second"
```

Comment: I believe part of your problem is that you are using a `Button` as a container for other `Widgets`. The `Button` is not intended to be a container, and does not support the properties that a `Layout` does. What is your intent in the `TestLayout`? Do you want the `DoubleLayout` to act as a `Button`?

Comment: @JohnAnderson `TestLayout` was meant to act as a final layout containing `Labels` with some information and i wanted to place it inside the `Button` widget (instead of button text because i needed to have multiple labels inside). It does not specifically have to be `Button` acting as container for layout with `Labels`, but i need button functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Good day. Widgets such as Buttons and Labels do not act as layouts for other widgets. Any widget added to another widget would appear in its default form (buttom left of screen with a size of 100 by 100 pixels). Please take a look at [layouts](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/layouts.html) and select an appropriate layout to place your widgets inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try a couple small changes in your `kv`. First, remove the Button from the `TestLayout`:

```
        BoxLayout:
            id: scroll_box
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: self.minimum_height
            spacing: 10

            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0, 1, 1, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            TestLayout:
                DoubleLayout:

            TestLayout:
                DoubleLayout:

            TestLayout:
                DoubleLayout:
```

Then, add a `Button` to the `DoubleLayout`:

```
<DoubleLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 0, 0.5
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    id: double_layout
    size_hint: 1, None
    pos: self.pos
    size: self.size
    rows: 1
    
    Button:
        text: 'do something'

    Label:
        text: "first"

    Label:
        text: "second"
```